# Software to keep (Python) code, text, diagrams in one place

Tags: python, programming, diagram, knowledge-organization

I’m searching for software which can do multiple things in the same file such as diagrams and drawings, text editing, and programming (hopefully Python). I know that Python can do lots of different things, but I’m looking to have my documentation and programming in the same file. For me, it’s important that I can organize my thoughts about a problem and create a solution for it plus of course programming in that same file.

Can anyone advise me on what’s available currently? Is there open source? Or will I have to pay? Will it be less expensive than Matlab and Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: I suggest a wiki. Wiki are very flexible though extensions, and can be freely hosted in wikifarms.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but it sounds a lot like **[Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/)**.
Such a notebook is essentially a series of cells, each of which can contain:

- Text, formatted in markdown (with MathJax support).
- Code in one of many languages including Python. Output produced by this code (including plots) is part of the notebook.

As for diagrams, I am not very familiar with the possibilities, but they can certainly be included if created with an external program.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second Wzrlpmft's suggestion regarding Jupyter notebooks, but if you're looking for something very different, you might check out the [Leo editor](https://leoeditor.com/).  It seems to require a certain kind of mindset to appreciate, and mine doesn't qualify, but maybe yours does.